# Файл ресурсов из другой сборки

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу организовать что-то типа dll с изображениями.
Во время выбора изображения[image]

в списке только файл ресурсов текущего проекта. (Скриншот окна выбора ресурса для компонента PictureBox из дизайнера)
Можно каким-нибудь образом добавить в этот список файл ресурсов из dll?

Comment: А что это за скриншот?

Comment: А зачем Вам `DLL` ? Если вы хотите получать изображения просто добавьте все рисунки в ресурсы, если я правильно понял, Вы именно это и хотите?